# How to use PreparedStatement in SQL having CASE statement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, case, prepared-statement

I have to update a column using `case` statement, but how do I set a `PreparedStatement` parameter over `case` statement. My code look like this:

```
PreparedStatement updateAkaunAmanahPs = con.prepareStatement(""
                                + "UPDATE GL_AKAUN_AMANAH "
                                + "   SET AMAUN_YOBCR = (CASE WHEN AMAUN_YOBCR IS NOT NULL THEN AMAUN_YOBCR = AMAUN_YOBCR + ? ELSE ? END) "
                                + " WHERE PKID = ?");

updateAkaunAmanahPs.setBigDecimal(1, ytddr.subtract(ytdcr));

// if the case statement is true, how about this parameter ?
updateAkaunAmanahPs.setBigDecimal(2, ytddr.subtract(ytdcr)); 

updateAkaunAmanahPs.setLong(3, 30);
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to consider the number of placeholder (`?`), in your case, you have 3 placeholders, then you need to set them accordingly (**in same order**)

```
updateAkaunAmanahPs.setBigDecimal(1, ytddr.subtract(ytdcr)); // for first placeholder
updateAkaunAmanahPs.setBigDecimal(2, ytddr.subtract(ytdcr)); // for second
updateAkaunAmanahPs.setLong(3, 30); // for third
```